# Magento 1.9 save() not working in modle but working in controller

Tags: magento-1.9

In the last days, I am using MySQL 4.1
and now MySQL version is 5.5
But when is am using 4.1 all save method is working but not they are not working in the model but work in the controller
2 days go and many time search on google but not get success. I am not sure why this is not working

Comment: can you place your code here ?

Comment: What do you mean by "all save method is working but not they are not working in model but work in controller " ? save method is available in model to save data in DB and you can access that method on model object from anywhere